# Can someone learn to cast a spell

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, optimization, cleric

I'm playing a Light domain Level 3 Cleric in D&D 5e.  Some of my spells are very important to the party.  I can't cast the spells many times.  I want to teach some of my companions to cast the 1st level spell *Inflict Wounds*. 
One of my friends who I plan to teach has +3 inteligence modifier and other one has +3 wisdom modifier and both of them are level 3 fighters.

Can I teach the spell? 
If I can, how long will it take?
Will it have lesser damage, and will the learner have lesser spell slots for that spell?

Comment: Have you spoken with your DM?  Are any of your companions Multi Classed?  Do any of them have feats related to spell casting?  Are you aware of the [distinction between Divine Casters and Arcane Casters](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/95583/22566)?

Comment: What is the class of the characters that your cleric is hoping to teach the spell to?   [Are they a spell casting class](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/83745/22566)?

Comment: Keep in mind that *Inflict Wounds* is likely to be much less effective for a fighter in most circumstances than whacking someone with a sword.

Comment: I stated that they are 3rd level fighters, not multiclassed, and have no feat related to spellcasting.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

## Yes, with a feat

The feat "Magic Initiate" can allow an ally to learn a 1st level spell and two cantrips from a given class. Your situation sounds like an unusually opportune moment to roleplay around the gaining of the feat, which your party members should have access to at fourth level, in place of their Ability Score Increase, if your DM has allowed feats.

Comment: Don't forget the other part of the answer.  NO, not without a feat.  non-spellcaster cannot just learn to cast spells without either a feat or multiclassing to a class with spellcasting abilities.

Answer (score 6):

If your DM allows [Unearthed Arcana](https://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/UA-Starter-Spells.pdf), there is a ritual the Cleric can cast called *Ceremony*, choosing the *Investiture* option, you can allow a willing humanoid to cast a 1st-level spell that you pay the slot for:

> ### Ceremony
>
> You perform one of several religious ceremonies. When you cast the spell, choose one of the following ceremonies, the target of which must be within 10 feet of you throughout the casting. 
>   ...
>   **Investiture.** You touch one willing humanoid. Choose one 1st-level spell you have prepared and expend a spell-slot and any material components as if you were casting that spell. The spell has no effect. Instead, the target can cast this spell once without having to expend a spell slot or use material components. If the target doesn't cast the spell within 1 hour, the invested slot is lost.

Of course, this is only a temporary solution, used for contingencies for when you foresee yourself getting knocked unconscious within the next hour. For a more permanent solution, [have your friend pick up a feat or multi-class into Cleric](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/96268/23064), if he can.